# Is it possible to save $_SESSION variables to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm new to PHP but know that $_SESSION per se is an array.

I have a form with some radio buttons. The button sends some data to a new .php file. After some script, it jumps back to the first .php page with the html form.
Here's the Problem: if the button is clicked again, the new data overwrites the data of the first time. But I want to save the data of all selections - if the user uses the buttons more than one time.

I need to use $_SESSION, because I want to print the values on the first page.

Or is it just wrong to work with (so many) $_SESSION variables?

Comment: You mean set an array like `$_SESSION['var'] = array(...);`?? Yes, you can do that and you would add a new _set_ of data like `$_SESSION['var'][] = array(...)` If there's a lot of data though you might want to put it into a database.

Comment: Okay that sound good. But how do I avoid the overwriting? Do I have to use it like this:
$_SESSION['collection'][0] = array($_SESSION['dataFromButtons']);
$_SESSION['collection'][1] = array($_SESSION['dataFromButtons']);
and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `$_SESSION` is one of PHP *superglobals*. However, for your purposes it is effectively the same as any other variable `e.g. $randomVariable`. The key difference being that `$_SESSION` is persistent between page loads.

That being the case we can make it an array like:

```
$_SESSION["dataForms"] = [];
```

We can then add *subarrays* to it like:

```
$_SESSION["dataForms"][] = [
    $_POST["formButton1"],
    $_POST["formButton2"],
    $_POST["formButton3"]
];
```

If you add multiple (e.g. three forms) in that way then you will get:

```
print_r($_SESSION);

/*
Array
(
    [dataForms] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => button1Value
                    [1] => button2Value
                    [2] => button3Value
                    [3] => button4Value
                    [4] => button5Value
                    [5] => button6Value
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => button1Value
                    [1] => button2Value
                    [2] => button3Value
                    [3] => button4Value
                    [4] => button5Value
                    [5] => button6Value
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => button1Value
                    [1] => button2Value
                    [2] => button3Value
                    [3] => button4Value
                    [4] => button5Value
                    [5] => button6Value
                )

        )

)
*/
```